# Как изменять код в зависимости от того, какой элемент ты выбрал?

Tags: javascript, интернет-магазин

У меня интернет магазин, хочу изменять элемент кода в зависимости от того, какую фирму я выбрал.

Для наглядности вот мои 4 фирмы: Estel, Epica, Kapous, Constant Delight.
Мне нужно чтоб я выбрала одну из фирм(перешел по ней) и изменялся код, сейчас объясню, где и зачем.

Данные всех товаров находятся в едином файле, для того чтобы эти данные разделять (данные товара, это его расположение название, фото) я ограничил все данные четырьмя переменными: catalogEstel, catalogEpica, catalogKapous, catalogConstant_Delight. А ограничил я для того чтоб в своей фирме, был свой товар(раньше у меня все товары были и в Estel, Epica, Kapous, Constant Delight и не было никаких разграничений).

Код который все это выводит выглядит это следующим образом:

```
    CATALOG.forEach(({id, name, price, img}) => {
    let activeClass = '';
    let activeText = '';

    if (productsStore.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        activeText = this.labelAdd;
    } else {
        activeClass = ' '+this.classNameActive;
        activeText = this.labelRemove;
    }
```

Если в начала написать допустим catalogEstel, то Estel и будет выводиться.
Мне нужно чтоб когда пользователь переходил на Estel код менялся на:

```
catalogEstel.forEach(({id, name, price, img}) => {
```

Когда переходил на Epica код становился:

```
catalogEpica .forEach(({id, name, price, img}) => {
```

И так было еще с Kapous и с Constant_Delight.

Для наглядности прикреплю фотографии чтоб было понятнее, заранее большое спасибо, сама разобраться не могу.

И я думала сделать если так получиться, то это было бы лучшим решение для меня:
У меня есть onclick на вот этих четырёх фирмах, возможно ли сделать onclick который будет изменять переменную, а именно её название.
То есть при клики на Estel, каталог заменяется на catalogEstel.
Клик на Epica, каталог изменяется на catalogEpica.

[image: Рис1]

[image: Рис2]

[image: Рис3]

[image: Рис4]

Comment: а, так это не в контексте одной страницы? и еще. так ты выбрал или сама?)

Comment: это называется фильтр - в тегах должен быть class или data-attr какой то который будет подходить под фильтр то есть нажимаем на class="item item-outer Estel" мы показываем все Estel а другие, все что не Estel скрываем

Answer (score 0):

1. Передавайте в свою функцию нужный вам объект

html:

```
<button class="logo" data-target="Estel">Estel</button>
<button class="logo" data-target="Epica">Epica</button>
```

Js:

```
let objectName = {
  "Epica": {
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "Notebook",
    "price": 10,
    "img": "url"
  },
  "Estel": {
    "id": 2,
    "name" : "Notebook",
    "price": 100,
    "img": "url"
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.logo').on('click', function(e){
          you_function($(this).data("target"))
   })
})

function you_function(name){
    console.log(objectName[name])
}
```

2. Добавлено. Если ваше событие висит на onclick, тогда так:

Html:

```
<button onclick="you_function('Estel')">Estel</button>
<button onclick="you_function('Epica')">Epica</button>
```

Js

```
    let objectName = {
      "Epica": {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Notebook",
        "price": 10,
        "img": "url"
      },
      "Estel": {
        "id": 2,
        "name" : "Notebook",
        "price": 100,
        "img": "url"
      }
    };

    function you_function(name){
        console.log(name) // имя
        console.log(objectName[name]) // вывод конкретного объекта
    }
```

Comment: Я думала сделать если так получиться, то это было бы лучшим решение для меня: У меня есть onclick на вот этих четырёх фирмах, возможно ли сделать onclick который будет изменять переменную, а именно её название. То есть при клики на Estel, каталог заменяется на catalogEstel. Клик на Epica, каталог изменяется на catalogEpica.

Comment: function you_function(name){
             console.log(you_function$(this).data("target"))
         } Хочу посмотреть правильную фирму ли выводит, но выходит только Estel

Comment: @pavloging Добавил в ответ. Обратите внимание, изменил в первом варианте опечатку в you_function. Вместо console.log(objectName["Estel"]) сделал console.log(objectName[name]); Но если вы говорите, что у вас все передается через onclick, тогда добавил второй вариант.